# MySql :Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column at row 1 in Enum datatype?

Tags: enums, mysql-workbench, mysql

I would like to use procedure on button click of more detailed search wherein if I enter all the input value then it is is displaying appropriate result. But, I would like to make my procedure more dynamic such that If I did not enter any Game_Platform then it will display all the records based on the other filters including the equivalent values for game_plaform. Also, if the platform or completeness or any other value is missing then also it should return the query result for all possible filter. So, how can I deal with below error for Enum Column?

**Procdeure call :** 
call sp_search_Records_on_all_conditions_With_Blank('asdasd','Extreme Sports','3','','','Good','2000-11-07','2011-06-15',12,67)

**Error Code:** 
1265. Data truncated for column 'Platform_Name_ip' at row 1 0.000 sec

Also, I would like to know how can I apply such filter on from date, to date, from price , to price?

Below is my Procedure, Could anyone please help me finding fault?

```
 USE `videogame_collection_1`;
       DROP procedure IF EXISTS      `sp_search_Records_on_all_conditions_With_Blank`;

       DELIMITER $$
       USE `videogame_collection_1`$$

           CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_search_Records_on_all_conditions_With_Blank`     (IN Game_Name_ip VARCHAR(100),IN Genre_ip ENUM('Controllers', 'Extreme Sports',    'Action & Adventure', 'Racing', 'RPG', 'Baseball', 'Sports', 'Systems',   'Puzzle', 'Fighting', 'Strategy', 'FPS', 'Wrestling', 'Accessories', 'Soccer',   'Other', 'Football', 'Party', 'Arcade', 'Basketball', 'Simulation', 'Music'),
 IN Rating_ip ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),IN Platform_Name_ip ENUM('N64',     'NES', 'Super Nintendo', 'Gamecube', 'Wii', 'Playstation 1', 'Playstation 2',    'Playstation 3', 'Xbox', 'Xbox 360', 'Sega Genesis', 'Atari 2600', 'Gameboy    Color', 'Gameboy Advance'),IN Completeness_Type_ip ENUM('B', 'I', 'C', 'BC',    'BI', 'IC', 'BIC'), IN Condition_ip ENUM('New', 'Mint', 'Very Good', 'Good',        'Acceptable', 'Poor'),
     IN from_Purchase_date_ip DATE,IN to_Purchase_date_ip DATE ,IN         from_Purchase_Price_ip DECIMAL(4,2), IN to_Purchase_Price_ip DECIMAL(4,2))
    Begin
     SET sql_mode = '';
     SELECT 
        video_game.Game_Name,
        video_game.Genre,
     video_game.Rating,
    platform.Platform_Name,
     mycollection.Completeness_Type,
         mycollection.`Condition`,
      mycollection.Purchase_Date,
     mycollection.Purchase_Price
     FROM
    video_game
        INNER JOIN
    video_game_platform_mycollection ON video_game.Game_Id =     video_game_platform_mycollection.Game_Id
        INNER JOIN
    platform ON video_game_platform_mycollection.Platform_Id =     platform.Platform_Id
        INNER JOIN
      mycollection ON video_game_platform_mycollection.MyCollection_Id =     mycollection.MyCollection_Id
    where (Game_Name_ip is null OR len(trim(Game_Name_ip)) > 0) or     video_game.Game_Name  LIKE CONCAT('%', Game_Name_ip, '%') and (Genre_ip is null     OR len(trim(Genre_ip)) > 0) or  video_game.Genre=Genre_ip and (Rating_ip is null    OR len(trim(Rating_ip)) > 0) or video_game.Rating=Rating_ip
     and (Platform_Name_ip is null OR len(trim(Platform_Name_ip)) > 0) or      platform.Platform_Name=Platform_Name_ip and (Completeness_Type_ip is null OR     len(trim(Completeness_Type_ip)) > 0) or      mycollection.Completeness_Type=Completeness_Type_ip and (Condition_ip is null OR     len(trim(Condition_ip)) > 0) or mycollection.`Condition`= Condition_ip
    and mycollection.Purchase_Date between from_Purchase_date_ip and     to_Purchase_date_ip and   mycollection.Purchase_Price >=from_Purchase_Price_ip     and mycollection.Purchase_Price<= to_Purchase_Price_ip;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```